# $\mathrm{e}^{2x+y+z}=x^2+y^2-2x-4y+4$ is a rotation surface?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, rotations

> $\mathrm{e}^{2x+y+z}=x^2+y^2-2x-4y+4$ is a rotation surface?

Why?

1. By translation, $e^{2u+v+w+4}=u^2+v^2-1$.
2. By orthogonal transform as $u=(2x+y+z)/6^{1/2}$, or $u=(2x+y)/5^{1/2}$, we do not find ...
3. Which translation and orthogonal transform should be put so that the surface becomes a rotation surface around $z$ axis?
4. Or what can be said easily why it is a rotation surface? Oh...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plot.  It doesn't look like a surface of rotation.

[image]